# How can one download the data in cloudkit?

Tags: ios

Apple cloudkit allows one to have a web server for their iOs app. But how can one download the data for their own use? Is it possible to download the data as a csv file?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. If it is, please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking. If not, please delete and post somewhere more appropriate.

Comment: There is no in-built data export tool.   You would have to build something using the web services interface.  Using that interface you can access public data and "your data". private data created by another iCloud user requires them to authenticate in order to access the data via the web interface.